# Material-UI: Using makeStyles and CSS-In-JS to target library elements styles

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks, css-in-js

I'm using `Material-UI` and building a form using `makeStyles` and `CSS-In-JS` to do the styling. I have a form from the Material-UI library that I am trying to style. I'm trying to figure out how to target classes that come from the library's form element and overwrite the styles.

Here is the form and the `Material-UI` class I'm trying to target (the form's first text input field's `before` tag):

[image]

I want to change the text field's `border-bottom` property. Here is what I've attempted. Look at the `underline` class in the CSS and the form's first text input:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
      display: 'flex',
      width: '100%',
      display: 'flex',
      alignItems: 'center'
    },
    container: {
        display: 'flex',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        height: '100vh'
    },
    paper: {
        padding: theme.spacing(2),
        display: 'flex',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        color: 'snow',
        background: 'salmon'
    },
    form: {
        background: 'salmon',
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'flex-start',
        height: '50vh',
        width: '50%'
    },
    customInput: {
        background: 'black'
    },
    underline: {
        '&:before': { 
            borderBottom: '10px solid green'
        },
      },
  }));
  
  export default function FormOne() {
    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
    <Grid container className={classes.container}>
        <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
            <Paper elevation="5" className={classes.paper}>
                <Formik
                    initialValues={{
                    email: '',
                    password: '',
                    }}

                    validate={values => {
                        const errors = {};
                        if (!values.email) {
                            errors.email = 'Required';
                        } else if (
                            !/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i.test(values.email)
                        ) {
                            errors.email = 'Invalid email address';
                        }
                        return errors;
                    }}

                    onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        setSubmitting(false);
                        alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
                    }, 500);
                    }}
                >
                    {({ submitForm, isSubmitting }) => (
                        <Form className={classes.form}>
                            <Field
                                component={TextField}
                                name="email"
                                type="email"
                                label="Email"
                                fullWidth="true"
                                variant="filled"
                                size="small"
                                color="primary"
                                className={classes.underline}
                            />
                            <br />
                            <Field
                                component={TextField}
                                type="password"
                                label="Password"
                                name="password"
                                fullWidth="true"
                                variant="filled"
                                size="small"
                                color="secondary"
                            />
                            <br />
                            <Field
                                component={TextField}
                                type="password"
                                label="Password"
                                name="password"
                                fullWidth="true"
                                variant="filled"
                                size="small"
                                color="primary"
                            />

                            {isSubmitting && <LinearProgress />}
                            <br />

                            <Button
                                variant="contained"
                                color="primary"
                                disabled={isSubmitting}
                                onClick={submitForm}
                                className={classes.button}
                                >
                                Submit
                            </Button>
                        </Form>
                    )}
                </Formik>
            </Paper>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
    );
  }
```

Normally when I use this approach to styling if I include `const classes = useStyles();` in my function I can then use `className={classes.nameOfClass}` on the element and then target that element in `makeStyles` and I can style elements. This works perfectly for custom elements I'm styling but does not work for overwriting `Material-UI` library classes.

How can I target `.MuiFilledInput-underline:before` in `makeStyles` and customize the styles?

Answer (score 1):

```
<Field classes={{ underline: classes.underline }} />
```

and

```
underline: {
  '&:before': {
    borderBottom: '10px solid green',
  },
},
```

The [API docs](https://material-ui.com/api/filled-input/#css) for every component will let you know how to target specific DOM elements

Answer (score 0):

You can do like @hotpink told, but this way you are going to change only the style of the element in this component ([here](https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#overriding-styles-classes-prop) for more details), but there is a better way to do it, if you want these changes to be applied to all elements along your project:

```js
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiButton: {
      root: {
        fontSize: '1rem',
      },
    },
  },
});
```

In the above example we change the css for the global class, you can see how we `overrides` the `root` class from the `MuiButton` element, this way all buttons are going to have the `fontSize` set to `1rem`. You can see the elements classes in the component API page of the component. Here an [example](https://material-ui.com/api/button/#css)

You can see the full docs with a lot of tutorials [here](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#global-theme-override) and I recommend you to read how to use the `ThemeProvider` [here](https://material-ui.com/customization/theming/)